# prevent footer from moving when window is resized vertically

Tags: html, css

How do you stick the footer to the bottom of the page and keep it from moving up, while the window resizes vertically? The footer should disappear when the the window gets smaller in terms of height.

This video shows how the footer moves: https://vid.me/Lqk6.

The problem is that the footer may overlap some content, when screen is resized. How do I prevent this from happening?

My code for the footer so far:

```css
 #footer{
  bottom: 0px;
  position:fixed;
  height:50px;
  left: 0px;
  right:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

}
#wrapper{
  height: 1000px;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly does `stick the footer to the bottom of the page and keep it from moving up` mean? Below all content as usual? Or first place it at window bottom and then later ignore the window? Obviously, it's sticking to the viewport bottom since you're specifying `position: fixed`, but what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Scroll down this website so you can see the footer. Now resize the window vertically. The footer gets hidden. That is the behaviour I was hoping for.

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/20pu9yvg/ ] can you please explain me where is the problem???

Comment: @sanjihan So can you tell me why you're using fixed positioning instead of just letting the footer go below the content in the normal layout flow?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid resize the window vertically and you will see that text overlaps with footer

Comment: Obviously I don't know what i am doing :D

Comment: @sanjihan try that fiddle when I resize the window vertically obviously some text hidden under the footer. whats wrong with that ?? look that site you posted there is a fixed navbar when you scroll up and down that navbar also hide some content

Comment: "The footer should disappear when the the window gets smaller in terms of height." Do you have a pixel height below which the footer should not display (then use mediaqueries) or do you want the footer to stop being fixed when you resize the window (then you will probably have to resort to using javascript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarmad Aijaz is correct-- the fixed positioning is causing the problem.  I think this will solve it for you:

```css
 #footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}

html,body {
    height: 100 % ;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

By setting the `#wrapper` to `position: relative;`, we ensure that the `#footer` absolute positioning will be *relative to the `#wrapper`* (as it is the first non-statically positioned parent element).  If you'd prefer it to be relative to the document, just omit the relative positioning on the `#wrapper` element.

Answer (score 1):

This solution depende which resoulosion of users' device.
You can configure it by using @media attribute.

Acordding to my device, I changed the folךowing 2 lines and it worked like you want:

top: 580px;
position:relative ;

Answer (score 0):

It is because your position is fixed in #footer...
you can change it to `absolute` or `relative`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the footer at the bottom of the text (sticky footer), but keep it from always staying at the bottom of the screen, you can use: `position: relative;` (keeps the footer in relation to the content of the page, not the view port) and `clear: both;` (will keep the footer from riding up on other content).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the body contents inside the "main" tag, which you want to get displayed in the middle and keep the footer inside the "footer" tag.
`<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      bla bla bla
    </header>
    rest of the body contents
  </main>
  <footer>
    bla bla bla
  </footer>
</body>`

I was also facing the same issue, when I added the "main" tag it worked.